# Grouping a Views table

Tags: drupal

I followed a simple Views Relationship example where I created a content type called Departments which has a User Reference field called employees, which can have multiple employee selected. You can see the view settings here;
http://files.nicklowman.co.uk/movies/images/view.png

The View then displays a table of Departments and Users who work in them, here.
http://files.nicklowman.co.uk/movies/images/list_ungrouped.gif

But in the example the guy styles his table using the ‘Grouping field’ set to Departments, here;
http://files.nicklowman.co.uk/movies/images/group_settings.png

And his view ends up looking like this
http://files.nicklowman.co.uk/movies/images/his_group.gif

But when I apply the exactly the same setting to my table it displays like this
http://files.nicklowman.co.uk/movies/images/list_grouped.png

What am I doing wrong? I read about the NodeReferrer module but the guy doesn’t mention it in his example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to select the 'Exclude from display' in the field settings for the Node title.

Thanks for your help Mike, it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing duplicates (on the views build page in the left column). That's just a guess.

Comment: Do you mean setting the Distinct to Yes? If so it made no difference. I have managed to get it to look like this http://files.nicklowman.co.uk/movies/images/lastest.png but it's still displaying the Dpartment data in the left column which his display doesn't. I even checked out his SQL ouput and it looks the same http://files.nicklowman.co.uk/movies/images/his_group.gif